# Page title getting hide when there is no data available in view

Tags: views

I have created a view for content and added no result behavior. But if there is no data available in view so title showing nothing(Page title block ). But I wanted to show title in all condition. For better understating please check attached images.
[image: My views look like this]

[image: Preview of test data]

But when I was trying to override title in contextual filter Content:Document type so as per replacement pattern I am only getting Title's ID that is I think correct way to do but how can i achieve it's name instead of ID. Please check attached images.
[image: No name available in replacement pattern only ID visible]

Comment: You've set the title to show `{{field_document_name}}` value, this value doesn't exist when there are no results and that's why you're not seeing a title

Comment: @Leigh What should I use instead of that? thanks

Comment: @Leigh If I am overriding title in Advance->Contextual filter-> content: Document type So according to replacement pattern Only Title ID are available not name e.g({{field_document_name}}) are available. By the way After Overriding ID its appearing in all condition as expect but I want to show name instead of it.